# Getting errors when trying to clone GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, cloning

Trying to clone a fork from Git using git bash doing `git clone https://github.com/jlord/patchwork.git`  and it gives me `clone succeeded but checkout failed`. I've checked other stack overflow posts and they've all said that it's either that there isn't enough space on my drive to download the repository or to enter the command `git config --system core.longpaths true` in Git bash.

I know it isn't a memory issue as my drive has hundreds of gigabytes of space left.

I've also tried `git config --system core.longpaths true` but it didn't work
**How can I undo this command?**

**How do I clone the repository from GitHub with no errors?**

Please answers some or all of the questions in bold.

Edit:
Here is the directory I am trying to fork https://github.com/RohanMuppa/patchwork

Original repo: https://github.com/jlord/patchwork

The local directory on my computer is D:\Coding\Repositories\desktop-tutorial

Comment: try this command `git config --system core.longpaths true` in command prompt which is launched by admin rights, like open as admin

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Thank You! I tried that but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: If you let us know the name git project (or, path), it would be helpful.

Comment: From my search, a space in the folder name of git repo might cause this problem.

Comment: @LunchBasketball Added it

Comment: @LunchBasketball Tried without spaces still didn't work

Comment: No issues with my env: Windows 10 (build) 17134 + git version 2.27.0.windows.1 works correctly. git clone https://github.com/RohanMuppa/hello-world => OK, git checkout -b test =>
Switched to a new branch 'test'

Comment: @LunchBasketball Yes my hello world directory works after a restart but the patchwork repo I just put in my post doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231131/discussion-between-rohan-muppa-and-lunch-basketball).

Answer (score 0):

> I've also tried `git config --system core.longpaths true` but it didn't work **How can I undo this command?**

If by "didn't work" you mean that you got an error that Git was unable to do it in the first place, there's nothing to undo.

If by "didn't work" you mean that you just want to change your system configuration back to the way it was before, well, we don't know for sure *how* it was before.  You can, however, *delete* this one configuration entry with:

```
git config --system --unset core.longpaths
```

or set it to false with:

```
git config --system core.longpaths false
```

(in both cases you will need the same kind of write access to the system configuration file that you would have needed to set `core.longpaths` to `true`).

> **How do I clone the repository from GitHub with no errors?**

There is some chance that you can't.

I took a brief look at the contents of the repository and it contains stuff that, when checked out, requires your OS to support files and/or folders whose name differs only in case.  If the errors you are getting are because your OS *does not* support that, this is not fixable here.  On macOS you can make a case-sensitive volume, and Windows probably has a similar method.

It's possible that some files and/or folders have names that are disallowed by your system (e.g., macOS cannot store one file named with separate letter-and-composing umlaut and a different one with a letter that already has the umlaut).

Note that viewing the repository on GitHub (either the original or the fork) shows both `CONTRIBUTORS` and `Contributors`, and both `Patchwork/contributors` and `patchwork/contributors`; these are obvious case-folding issues.

Note that when checkout fails, your Git will report more specific failures, which may help you pin down which names need what kind of correction to work on your system.

Comment: I am using windows so would I be fine if I used a virtual machine with linux or mac on it? If you are a windows user did it work for you just so we can make sure this is a windows problem and not one specific to my computer?

Comment: I'm not a Windows user, but yes, if you fire up a VM and run Linux on it and clone you should be OK. Linux is pretty permissive about file names.